# Django ManifestStaticFilesStorage not loading the correct static files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am using a combination of `django-storages` and `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` to server static files and media from `S3`.

```
class StaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

When I run `collectstatic` I can see the newest version of my `JS` file on S3 with the correct timestamp.

I can also see that file being referenced in the `staticfiles.json` manifest.

However looking at the site in the browser I am still seeing the old `JS` being pulled down, not the one in the `manifest`

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Same problem for me. I'm checking out WhiteNoise instead

Comment: did you ever end up figuring this out?

Comment: Does a restart fix it?  I think the staticfiles.json is loaded once on startup.

Answer (score 2):

The `staticfiles.json` seems to be loaded once when the server starts up (from the S3 instance).  If you run `collectstatic` while the server is running it has no way of knowing that there were changes made to S3.  You need to restart the server after running `collectstatic` if changes have been made.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this post](https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/a-hidden-gem-in-django-1-7-manifeststaticfilesstorage) for more infomation. In short:

> By default staticfiles.json will reside in STATIC_ROOT which is the
>   directory where all static files are collected in. We host all our
>   static assets on an S3 bucket which means staticfiles.json by default
>   would end up being synced to S3.

So if your `staticfiles.json` being cached, your static files will be the old ones.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

- Versionize `staticfiles.json` like you're already done with your static files
- Keep `staticfiles.json` in local instead of S3

Comment: Another alternative is to use `CachedFilesMixin` which stores the data in the cache instead of a file.  ... it doesn't seem to pre-process the hashes, though, but does it on each file request, so not ideal.